# Circuitikz - pgfkeys error with the 'invert' command: How do I invert my Voltage source?

Tags: errors, circuitikz, pgfkeys

The Latex *CircuiTikZ* documentation [v0.8.3] says:

> "Bipole paths can also mirrored and inverted (or reverted) to change
>   the drawing direction."

Example:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[pD, invert] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

But running my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}


    \begin{circuitikz} \draw
        (0,0)   to[R=$R$, o-] (2,0)
        to[V=$V$, invert] (3,0);

    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Gives the following error:

> "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/invert' and I am
>   going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
>   to[V=$L_eI_{q1}\omega_e$, invert] (3,0)"

Any suggestions on fixing this error and getting the invert command to work?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I can't reproduce your error. It works fine for me. Have you checked your packages?

Comment: When you see a key error with a key name belonging to a third party package and key family being tikz, here for example `/tikz/invert` it usually means that the third party could not handle the key itself and thought *it must be a TikZ key*. Hence probably you have a circuitikz version that doesn't understand `invert` key. Try updating first. Or you are using the key in the wrong context.

Comment: @percusse, the context is ok. The code works with actual circuitikz 0.8.3 release.

Comment: It seems like I have an error updating with tlmgr - I remember doing some dodgy things when I first installed TexLive. Shall I delete this question since the real problem is an installation one?

Comment: When you load the circuitikz package, it works also in the tikzpicture environment, just for a test, try changing the `begin{circuitikz} ...  end{circuitikz}` environment by `\begin{tikzpicture} ... end{tikzpicture}`because in my compiler the first one generates warnings.